# Two string region compare in java

Tags: java, string

I have two string (str1, str2) and the use case is like this

1) compare last i characters in str1 with first i characters in str2

2) compare first i characters in str1 with last i characters in str2

I know how to do in c++ like below

```
int len1 = str1.length();
int len2 = str2.length();
```

1)

```
str1.compare(len1-i, i, str2, 0, i)
```

2)

```
str1.compare(0, i, str2, len2-i, i)
```

How to achieve same thing in java with regionMatches method or something else. Not able to figure out.

Comment: Use the substring() method on the String class to extract the text you need, and then use the equals() method to compare the resulting Strings.  (See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)).  Or have a look at the documentation for regionMatches() - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#regionMatches(boolean,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int).

Answer (score 2):

It should be easy to figure it out by a simple look into the API documentation. ;)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/String.html

There are at least two options for you:

A)

```
str1.endsWith(str2.substring(i))
str2.endsWith(str1.substring(i))
```

B)

Assuming (thus not validating) that both strings contain at least *i* characters:

```
str1.regionMatches(0, str2, str2.length() - i - 1, i)
str1.regionMatches(str1.lenght() - i - 1, str2, 0, i)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you could get it done by regionMatches:

```
String str1 = new String("Hello, How are you");
String str2 = new String("How do you do?");
System.out.print("Result of Test1: " );
System.out.println(str1.regionMatches(7, str2, 0, 3));
```

Result:

`Result of Test1: true`

Comment: str1.regionMatches(7, str2, 0, 3) is useful when you want to match the last i characters of str1 with first character of str2. How do you do it in reverse way that is first i character of str1 with last i character of str2?

Comment: `startsWith` and `endsWith` may be your solution, then? `IndexOf` is another solution, too.